# ¿Como puedo poner un background en general para un proyecto en Vue?

Tags: html, css

Trato de poner un background que abarque toda la pagina pero solo se pone en cierta parte, cabe recalcar que estoy empezando a programar en vue

El color lo estoy colocando desde la App.vue, dejo el codigo en caso de ser necesario

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-navbar id="navBar" toggleable="lg" type="dark">
      <b-container>
        <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
        <b-navbar-brand :to="{ name: 'Me' }"
          >Juan Manuel Restrepo Moreno</b-navbar-brand
        >
        <b-collapse is-nav id="nav-collapse">
          <b-navbar-nav>
            <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'skill' }"
              >Habilidades y Conocimiento</b-nav-item
            >
            <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'curriculum' }">Curriculum</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'portfolio' }">Portafolio</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-container>
    </b-navbar>
    <b-container>
      <router-view />
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  background: #182a3f;
}
#navBar {
  background-color: #232f3e;
}
</style>
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes forzar a que el contenido de #app cubra al menos la parte visible de la pagina.

```
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #182a3f;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Ademas puedes evitar que body muestre un borde/padding agregando:

```
body{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
```

Para aplicar el fondo a nivel general (no solo #app) puedes pasar dichas propiedades a body:

```
body{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #182a3f;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Gracias con loa que me digiste ya pude hacer el cambio de background

Answer (score 0):

Te respondo como respuesta para poder poner código, pero más bien sería un comentario.

Diría que lo que preguntas está más relacionado con `CSS` que con `VueJs`.

Prueba a ponerle la propiedad background a la etiqueta `body` en vez de `#app`.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Cuando hablas de la etiqueta body seria en el index.html, porque trate colocandolo desde hay y no me fue posible arreglar el error